# Why would a pilot with a current medical use BasicMed?

Tags: faa-regulations, medical, basicmed

A pilot whose certificate I just looked up has both a valid second class medical and a BasicMed CMEC date listed. Why would a pilot with a valid medical use BasicMed?

Comment: How do you look up other pilot's medical certificates, and how is this not a HIPPA violation?

Comment: @MichaelHall it seems easy to look that up in the [FAA database](https://amsrvs.registry.faa.gov/airmeninquiry/Main.aspx).

Comment: Interesting... this seems a bit private to be putting in a searchable database, especially without the Pilot Cert # as a required field.

Comment: @MichaelHall yeah, it just comes up when you search for their pilot certificate. It's not kept private at all. Apparently the certificate number and date of birth are the only things shown on the plastic certificate but not online.

Comment: @Someone Pilots can also request that their address not be released, and then it will not show the address either.

Comment: @MichaelHall the FAA is not a healthcare provider, and thus HIPAA does not apply to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any number of reasons.

It could be that their medical expired and they were operating under BasicMed until they could renew it. It could be that they are planning not to renew their medical and just operate under BasicMed once it expires. It could be that they want to still be good to fly if their medical is deferred in the future. It could even be that they just want to be covered in case they misplace their medical and want to keep flying until the replacement arrives.